# Usage of "this" in terraform import command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to import some resources ( created by EKS outside terraform) specifically [cluster creator access entry.](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_access_entry#import)

The documentation provides this usage to create new access entry

```
locals {
  access_entries = {
    iam_identity_center_admin_role = {
      kubernetes_groups = []
      principal_arn     = data.external.get_sso_admin_role.result.Arn
      policy_associations = {
        iam_identity_center_admin_role = {
          policy_arn = "arn:aws:eks::aws:cluster-access-policy/AmazonEKSClusterAdminPolicy"
          access_scope = {
            type = "cluster"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to [terraform import command docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import)

> Before you run terraform import you must manually write a resource configuration block for the resource. The resource block describes where Terraform should map the imported object.

Based on the above understanding I tried to use the following import command which throws error

```
terraform import  module.base.module.eks.aws_eks_access_entry.iam_identity_center_admin_role mycluster:principal arn

Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in module.base.module.eks. For example:
    resource "aws_eks_access_entry" "iam_identity_center_admin_role" {
      # (resource arguments)
    }
```

**The same works if I add the terror resource for eks access entry. Of course when I use resource definition I don't use the locals of access entries map.　So, it's not correct resource problem**

```
resource "aws_eks_access_entry" "imported_cluster_creator_eks_access_entry" {
  cluster_name  = local.eks_name
  principal_arn = data.external.get_sso_admin_role.result.Arn
}
```

But if I use the following import command **with locals and not explicit resource definition** having `this` it works . I want to know why the usage of this works? why this is used? To my understanding it is implicitly used

```
terraform import 'module.base.module.eks.aws_eks_access_entry.this["iam_identity_center_admin_role"]' my-cluster:pricipal arn
```

Comment: can you show the module code? it looks like the `aws_eks_access_entry` resource in the module is called `this` and is using a `for_each` meta to create multiple items

Comment: Which module are you using, custom or publicly available?

Comment: I am using terraform-eks-module public

Comment: `this` is a convention in Terraform configs for a resource name with no distinguishing characteristics such as in a module that would generally manage a given set of resources with no dedicated purpose. The two above comments are leading toward either the `import` subcommand using an incorrect namespace, or an incorrect resource being targeted. Both are most likely root cause here for the issue.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra can you share the code you have as well?

Comment: @MarkoEsharing code will be difficult as it is not a test code but this isn't a namespace or incorrect resource problems as the command which fails works when I add the access_entry resource configuration. let me add to my question

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Yeah, no problem, I was thinking more along the lines of where did you get the `local` variable and how are you passing it to the EKS module, I tried answering based on provided information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the terraform module code, the [`merged_access_entries`](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/main.tf#L159-L162) local variable is used with the `aws_eks_access_entry` resource. Since the resource you have created manually needs to be imported into the module, you have to follow the convention specified by the said module. In this case, the resource you want to import is using the logical name of [`this`](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/main.tf#L185-L195):

```
resource "aws_eks_access_entry" "this" {
  for_each = { for k, v in local.merged_access_entries : k => v if local.create }

  cluster_name      = aws_eks_cluster.this[0].name
  kubernetes_groups = try(each.value.kubernetes_groups, null)
  principal_arn     = each.value.principal_arn
  type              = try(each.value.type, "STANDARD")
  user_name         = try(each.value.user_name, null)

  tags = merge(var.tags, try(each.value.tags, {}))
}
```

As you can see, the EKS module is also using `for_each` to create the resource `aws_eks_access_entry`, hence the need for the key when specifying the `import` command as the key-value pairs are decided from the `merged_access_entries` local variable. Based on everything outlined here and in your question, you are calling the EKS module from the `base` module.

When using modules, you need to know which resource and resource's logical name are used **in the module you want to import to** in order to successfully import it. Since the resource in question is `"aws_eks_access_entry" "this"`, the entire import command needs to be:

```
terraform import module.base.module.eks.aws_eks_access_entry.this["iam_identity_center_admin_role"]' <cluster:pricipal arn>
```

because one of the keys in the local `access_entries` variable which you have defined is `iam_identity_center_admin`.

Answer (score 2):

The [eks module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/main.tf#L185) defines the `aws_eks_access_entry` resource with a name called `this`. It then uses a `for_each` meta to loop over all the entries it needs to create

```
resource "aws_eks_access_entry" "this" {
  for_each = { for k, v in local.merged_access_entries : k => v if local.create }

  cluster_name      = aws_eks_cluster.this[0].name
  kubernetes_groups = try(each.value.kubernetes_groups, null)
  principal_arn     = each.value.principal_arn
  type              = try(each.value.type, "STANDARD")
  user_name         = try(each.value.user_name, null)

  tags = merge(var.tags, try(each.value.tags, {}))
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, `this` doesnt do anything special, its just a name for the `aws_eks_access_entry` resource. Using `this` is just general convention for a general purpose resource in a module.

you can read more on [naming](https://www.terraform-best-practices.com/naming) which says

> Resource name should be named this if there is no more descriptive and general name available, or if the resource module creates a single resource of this type (eg, in AWS VPC module there is a single resource of type aws_nat_gateway and multiple resources of typeaws_route_table, so aws_nat_gateway should be named this and aws_route_table should have more descriptive names - like private, public, database).